# How can I log in Play Framework using Scala?

Tags: scala, logging, playframework, play-framework-2.7

I have updated Play Framework up to 2.7 and I got following warning:

```
method info in object Logger is deprecated (since 2.7.0): Create an instance of via Logger(...) and use the same-named method. Or use SLF4J directly.
```

**So my questions are:**

- Should I create an instance of Logger and pass it to each component
  when I want to use it?

**P.S.:**

In project not based on Play Framework, I used to use [scala-logging](https://index.scala-lang.org/lightbend/scala-logging/scala-logging/3.9.0) that is a wrapper for SLF4J. Can this be a solution?

Comment: I would recommend to create a logger instance on each class, the java way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Play 2.7 provides a trait for **Scala** similar to scala-logging. It creates a `val` which you can use it in you class/object:

```
import play.api.Logging

class MyClass extends Logging {
  // `logger` is automaticaly defined by the `Logging` trait:
  logger.info("hello!")
}
```

So there is another way to log in Play now.